# Execute a shell script with php

Tags: php, shell, hadoop

I need to execute a **shell script** through **php**. I am using **Apache** web server to run my php pages.

I know there are other questions similar to mine (that i have already gone through), but for some reasons i am not able to make mine work.

Here is my **php** file:

```
<?php

$output = shell_exec('sh /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/copytoallhdfs.sh');

echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>";

?>
```

Here is my shell script  **copytoallhdfs.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=`bin/hdfs dfs -ls -C /`
echo $myarray; 

for name in $myarray 
do bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal myData/* $name; 
done
```

My  **copytoallhdfs.sh** script is located on the path `/usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2​` .  So normally php should be executing my shell script and displaying the output of `echo $myarray;`, but nothing is displaying on my browser.

Maybe it is some permissions problems or something missing in my **php.ini** but i just can't solve this problem.
Can anyone please give me a work around for this.

Thank you.

Comment: PD of [How can I debug exec() problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12199353)

Comment: @mario i could make it work. Thanks for the additional support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @nacho 's comment, i thought if it was something to do about the location of my **sh** **script**. I edited my sh script and inserted `pwd` to verify the location it is giving me. Then i realized that it was giving me the location of my apache directory.

So i changed the location and inserted the full path to execute the command `bin/hdfs`.
It worked!

Here is my updated script:

```
#!/bin/bash

myarray=`/usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/bin/hdfs dfs -ls -C /`
echo $myarray;

for name in $myarray
do /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/bin/hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/myData/* $name;
done
```

That was kind of a silly mistake, but i guess it can happen!

Answer (score 1):

Use `2>&1` in order to achive that

```
$output = shell_exec('sh /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/copytoallhdfs.sh 2>&1');
```

`2` refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. stderr.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. stdout.

Comment: I am having this as output on my browser `/usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/copytoallhdfs.sh: 1: /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/copytoallhdfs.sh: bin/hdfs: not found`

Honestly i did not quite understand the `2>1&1` .

Comment: 2>&1 it takes the response and send's it further to srdout or to your variable. I don't know what exactly are you trying to achieve in shell.

Comment: Try to use absolute path for bin/hdfs in yuour script file as **/bin/hdfs**

Comment: I am not sure if you have ever used Hadoop, but my shell script will upload data files to Hadoop. Firstly it loops the hadoop file system to retrieve all folders available, then it will upload data files to these folders.

The line `echo $myarray;` should display all the folders available in hadoop, but it is not displaying on my browser.

I have did run my shell script with `./copytoallhdfs.sh`, there is no problem.

Comment: In that case maybe it's a permission problem, because php runs scrits in the name of `www-data` user. Do a `chmod` or a `chown` on that directory or use `sudo`.

Comment: `shell_exec('sudo sh /usr/local/hadoop-3.0.2/copytoallhdfs.sh 2>&1');`

Comment: @nacho This does not work also.

@AndreiLupuleasa I changed the owner and group of `copytoallhdfs.sh` script to `www-data` . This does not work either. 

Before, i created a simple sh script with `echo good`. I executed that script with php and it worked fine, i could see **good** appearing on my browser. 
Am really out of ideas!